# Getting rid of ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (Rails 3, webrick, devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, webrick

Cannot figure this one out.  Developing Rails 3.0.3 app using Devise 1.1.5, running locally on WEBrick 1.3.1.  Out of nowhere I get a

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

error on login (successful or not) and registration.  The app is deployed to Heroku, and works fine in production.  It also works fine on another dev's machine, running on Apache/Passenger.  No matter what I do I can't get rid of this error locally (and it ran fine several days ago until this error popped up mid-development).

I've checked out fresh code, restarted machine, run on different ports, wiped out db, everything I can think of.  No caching in the app.

Application trace is blank. Full trace below:

```
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:96:in `verify_authenticity_token'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `_run__2106070066__process_action__1623385099__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:120:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:35:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:295:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:353:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:30
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:27
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**:  Here's the post from the log:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jan 13 11:04:43 -0700 2011
  Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign in", "authenticity_token"=>"5R+ZYh3w/GiQwTdXExqj5O1u7Jkhrg2wclO1jfYvP5k=", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"jason.lynes@gmail.com"}}
Completed   in 1ms

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

Comment: Please add the section of your log which shows the request params to your question. Your question can't be answered without knowing if the csrf token is actually being sent.

Comment: Added the log with post params.

Comment: Thanks for adding in the request log. Alas, I can't see anything wrong here. I'd suggest trying `passenger start` rather than webrick and perhaps also trying with another browser. I suppose it's possible that a different site running at the same address (http://localhost:3000/) has set its own _csrf_token in a session and is interfering.

Comment: so passenger works great. no errors.  and i do work on localhost:3000 for tons of apps.  i imagine that's what's happening.  bye bye webrick.  thanks!

Answer (score -3):

The other thing you might try is to add:

```
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
```

into your development environment file.

Comment: That is bad advice! Never ever disable forgery protection.

Comment: agreed in production, but for dev it seems reasonable. No?

Comment: "Reasonable" is not the word I would use :-) It's a hacky solution that could introduce other errors. Better fix the real problem than hack around it.